# Windows Azure Mobile Services and Compression

Tags: gzip, azure-mobile-services

Does Windows Azure Mobile Services supports GZIP Compression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this moment. Feel free to post this feature request in the [MSDN forums for Azure Mobile Services](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuremobile/threads), and the team will consider it.

Comment: An update - it's now supported in all platforms, see the comment at http://mobileservices.uservoice.com/forums/182281-feature-requests/suggestions/3504131-gzip-compression-between-server-and-client